# Connected Component on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, connected-components

I want to understand how Neo4j's **Connected component** function `unionFind` works ?
in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/connected-components/) i found that it returns :
[image: unionFind 's return]
so i am asking what are this two integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodeId` is the native node ID assigned by the DB to each node. You can gat a node's native ID via the Cypher function [ID()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-id).

The `setId` is a connected subgraph's "Partition ID". All the nodes in the same connected subgraph will share the same Partition ID.

Comment: How the *partition ID* is affected to each subgraph is it  just a random integer ?

Comment: It is not random. If you really want to see the details of how it is generated, you can look at the version 3.5 source code for `findPC(int p)` [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/blob/3.5/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/core/utils/dss/DisjointSetStruct.java).